# C# Http server - handling multiple requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpserver

I am using this HttpServer class for handling http requests and expirencing problem while receiving multiple requests. HttpServer instance is created on MainForm and if MainForm works on some heavy tasks, HttpServer doesn't handle requests until Main finishes those tasks. Why it behaves like that even though HttpServer listens and handles requests on a different thread.

Instance creation code on MainForm:

```
HTTPServer httpServer = new HTTPServer("https", "5000");
```

I also tried creating it on its own thread but it didn't helped:

```
(new Thread(() => { new HTTPServer("https", "5000"); })).Start();
```

HTTPServer Class code:

```
    public class HTTPServer
    {
    bool listenerStop = false;
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    string prefixFormat = "{0}://+:{1}/";
    string prefix = "";
    Thread t;

    public HTTPServer(string protocol, string port) {
        string prefix = String.Format(prefixFormat, protocol, port);
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread));
        t.Start();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        t.Abort();
    }

    public void serverThread() {
        try {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported) return;
            listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
            listener.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        while (!listenerStop)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(listenerCallback), listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }        

    private void listenerCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
        try
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            //Do work...
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
           //Http server error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WaitOne will cause the serverThread to block while it is waiting for the callback to finish. Since the callback is on your main thread this means that you are blocked until it finishes with its work.

Refactor so you don't need a wait statement and you will eliminate your blocking issue.

Comment: serverThread method is started on its own thread and BeginGetContext that is called from serverThread should start every request on a different thread. So I don't understand why processing of requests doesn't seem to be multitreaded.

Comment: It is. But then you tell the server thread to wait until that thread is done, which will block the server thread until it completes. Effectively undoing your async/threading by blocking.

Comment: But shouldn't call to EndGetContext unblock the calling thread? It's called at the beggining of listenerCallback so even though processing of request continues, serverThread should be unblocked and be able to receive and handle another request.